# Compiling .cs from .Net Applications

Tags: c#

Is there a managed API to compile C# applications (to memory or disk)?  I assume one exists because SharePoint compiles ASP.NET pages in memory.  We want to use it to, at runtime, generate Linq `DataContext`s and compile those against various projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class. That page has sample code how to use that class to compile C# sources.

**Note**: This class cannot be use in partial trust. You need to run with full trust in order to be able to run the C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

As Franci has pointed out, the CSharpCodeProvider is what you want.

While writing my C# book I built "Snippy" which is a quick'n'dirty way of building and running snippets of C# - it's a simple enough project to make it quite easy to see how to use CSharpCodeProvider. The [full source](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) is available - take a look.